# `helm upgrade` patch deployment when there is no change

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a little problem using a helm chart as umbrella chart.
-> https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#complex-charts-with-many-dependencies

When i'm performing a `helm upgrade` without changes, helm applies a patch on all my deployments even if there are no changes.

`my-chart/Chart.yml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: sample-umbrella-chart
description: sample umbrella chart
version: 0.1.0

dependencies:
  - alias: some-service
    name: some-chart
    repository: "oci://some-repository"
    version: 1.0.0
```

`helm upgrade`:

```bash
helm upgrade --debug --wait \
  --namespace some-namespace \
  -f some-values.yaml \
  sample-umbrella-chart \
  /path/to/the/chart/sample-umbrella-chart \
  --install
```

I tried to remove all flags like `--debug` or `--install` without any successful attempt.

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]?  I've had a number of problems using umbrella charts; can you independently deploy the component services, maybe using a higher-level tool like Helmfile to orchestrate them?

Comment: I can't provide a minimal reproducible example. Use tools like `Helmfile` is an option but I want to use a minimum number of "external" tools. I take it as my last option.